# Spring Boot 1.5.10 to 2.0 Spring Data Mongo @Query

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am having one last issue with the migration from Spring Boot 1.5.10 to 2.0.  My queries that are annotated with the @Query do not work anymore.  In 1.5.10, these worked just fine:  Here is the query and entity:

```
@Document(collection = "credentials")
public class Credentials implements Serializable, Comparable<Credentials>
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -921533822040690113L;

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Indexed
    @Field("userId")
    private UUID userId;

    @Field("access")
    private List<Access> access;

    @Field("roles")
    private List<String> roles;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public UUID getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(UUID id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userId
     */
    public UUID getUserId()
    {
        return userId;
    }

    /**
     * @param userId the userId to set
     */
    public void setUserId(UUID userId)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the access
     */
    public List<Access> getAccess()
    {
        return access;
    }

    /**
     * @param access the access to set
     */
    public void setAccess(List<Access> access)
    {
        this.access = access;
    }

    /**
     * @return the roles
     */
    public List<String> getRoles()
    {
        return roles;
    }

    /**
     * @param roles the roles to set
     */
    public void setRoles(List<String> roles)
    {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public Credentials()
    {}
```

The query is this:

```
public interface ICredentialsRepository extends MongoRepository<Credentials, UUID>
{

    /**
     * This query finds the credentials by userId
     * @param userId user identification
     * @return Credentials object
     */
    @Query("{ 'userId' : ?0}")
    Credentials retrieveWithUserId(UUID userId);
}
```

When running this now, I get the error

```
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'unknown operator: $uuid' on server
```

Once again, this worked perfectly in Spring Boot 1.5.10.  Included with the project is spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-2.0.0 and spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.0.0

Comment: Why are you using a string query instead of query derivation (`findByUserId(UUID)`)? String values are serialized to BSON/JSON and MongoDB's JSON encoder creates `$uuid: …`.

Comment: The query derivation does work.  For this example, I could use that.  However, all of my other "@Query" operations are erroring out with the same error.  Example "@Query("{ 'institutionId' : ?0 , 'startDate' : {'$gte': ?1}, 'dateArchived' : null}")"  errors with the same error.  institutionId is a UUID but not the primary key "_id"

Comment: Changing the UUID to a string results in the query not bringing back any records when it was bringing the correct records back before.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your UUID it's not a entity/document type. You should use @Document on UUID class and @Embedded and @Embeddebable on UUID class and UUID reference in your Credentials class.

Comment: Just to be clear, the UUID is part of the Java JDK and is a representation of the GUID provided by MongoDB.  I will try the @Embeddable on the object declaration.

Comment: Ok, that "@Embedded" solution is not working.  The interesting thing is that the "@Id" has no problem with the UUID.  It only has a problem with the "@Query "annotation.  For this  one, if I remove the "@Query" annotation and rename the method to findByUserId and it works.  There are other queries in the application that do not work either.  They are erroring out with the same type of issue.